# How to generate random automorphisms on finite field vector spaces?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

I want to make random combinatorial puzzles of this format:

There are 7 lights and 7 buttons. Each button switches certain lights between off/on. The buttons and lights start at "off".

To generate such a puzzle randomly, I would generate a random basis $\{v_1, ... v_7\}$ of the vector space $Z_2^7$, so that each switch $i$ controls the lights that are given $1$ in the vector $v_i$.

This is essentially generating a random basis for $Z_2^7$. How would I do that?

Comment: The first algorithm that occurs to me would be to: first select a random non-zero vector to be your $v_1$. Then, in step $j$, $2\le j \le 7$, select a random vector $v_j$ not in the linear span of $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_{j-1}\}$.

Comment: But could make a fun game :-)